# How does cv::imdecode know the dimensions of the result?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to translate the following function to C++:

```
def base64_2_mask(s):
    z = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(s))
    n = np.fromstring(z, np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.imdecode(n, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[:, :, 3].astype(bool)
    return mask
```

It decodes a JSON string into a `cv::Mat` mask.

I am doing pretty well, except for the part

```
const cv::Mat bitmap( size, CV_8UC1, decompressed.data() );
const auto decoded = cv::imdecode( bitmap, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED );
```

I don't know what `size` to pass here. The python version deduces it automatically. Here is a sample run:

```
>>> a = base64_2_mask("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")
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> a.shape
(427, 294)
>>> b = "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"
>>> z = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(b))
>>> n = np.fromstring(z, np.uint8)
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
>>> n
array([137,  80,  78, ...,  66,  96, 130], dtype=uint8)
>>> n.shape
(1415,)
>>> mask = cv2.imdecode(n, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[:, :, 3].astype(bool)
>>> mask.shape
(427, 294)
>>> mask2 = cv2.imdecode(n, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
>>> mask2.shape
(427, 294, 4)
```

[Here](https://github.com/MiroslavVitkov/silhouette/blob/master/src/bitmap.cpp) is my code.

Comment: You're creating a `Mat` header for the data stored in `decompressed`, so the size would be the number of bytes in `decompressed`...

Comment: @DanMašek hmmmm `(427 * 294) / 1415` is not a whole number.

Comment: It's a buffer containing a PNG that holds compressed data, not a raw image, so there won't be any meaningful relationship between the size of input and the size of decoded output.